# Change title width in JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, dialog

I've created a dialog object as it follows:

```
confirmDialog = $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
```

I'm hiding the close button with the class "no-close":

```
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

Problem is, despite not visible, the button is still taking space in the dialog titlebar, and moves the title slightly on the left.

```
<span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Deleting Record</span>
<button type="button" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close"></button>
```

[image: Title not centered]

The only way I found to center it back, is to wide the span containing the title. (F12 in Chrome and changed manually).

```
<span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title" style="width: 310px">Deleting Record</span>
```

[image: Title manually centered]

How can I add the property style to the object `span`?

Comment: Try giving that span a css rule that makes it `display:block`

Comment: Adding the CSS you want in a CSS file will be much better than inline `style` property, you could use `span.ui-dialog-title{ width: 310px; }`

Comment: @Taplar that's not working.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I already use the CSS to change the title font-size in that span. No success on that front. It just ignores the width I'm giving.

Comment: Then right click the element and inspect it to see what CSS rule is overrideing your rule.  More granular CSS rules take precedence over less specific rules.  When you find the rule, you can either make a more granular or, or use `!important`.

Comment: Try first to be more specific using the identifiers like `#confirmDialog span#ui-id-1{ width: 310px; }`.

Comment: @Taplar saves the day. `!important` did it. That was something I didn't know about CSS. Thanks for your help.